# How can I remove the contents of the next element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to empty next div html data using jquery

```
$('#deleteAssocPesident').click(function(e){
  // e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);

  $(this).next('div').next('#deletePresidentBlock').html('');
});
```

Html

```
<div class="user_president_designation" id="user_designation_president">President <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" id="deleteAssocPesident" style="float: right;font-size: 22px;margin-top: 4px;" ></i></div>
<div class="user_president_block" id="deletePresidentBlock">
  <img src="" style="max-width: 300px;max-height: 300px;min-height: 300px;" class="img img-responsive" />
  <div class="user_president_name">{{$firstName}}&nbsp;{{$lastName}}</div>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="president">
</div>
```

I have tried many methods but its not working .I am sure this function is working it might be the issue of next cant able to find div
Any help is appriciated

Updated

I have many similar block so i cant use id .so i have empty closest delete div block

Now i have added class name `deletePresidentBlock` since id should be unque

Comment: Since you have an ID on the field why not just `$('#deletePresidentBlock').html('')`

Comment: [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) *Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.*.  If you are trying to reference an ID, it would make sense to just empty on that ID since they are **unique**.

Comment: @Cfreak.i have many block so if add like that it will delete all.i want to remvoe particular bock which user clicked

Comment: Try [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: @vision IDs must be unique. If they are not unique you should be using a class instead. In those cases I find `.find()` to work better than `.next()`

Comment: @Cfreak.thanks.i have added class now and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('#deleteAssocPesident').click(function(e){
  $(this).closest('div#user_designation_president').next('#deletePresidentBlock').html('');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user_president_designation" id="user_designation_president">President   <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" id="deleteAssocPesident" style="float: right;font-size: 22px;margin-top: 4px;" ></i>
</div>
<div class="user_president_block" id="deletePresidentBlock">
  <img src="" style="max-width: 300px;max-height: 300px;min-height: 300px;" class="img img-responsive" />
  <div class="user_president_name">{{$firstName}}&nbsp;{{$lastName}}</div>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="president">
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @vision Welcome buddy :)

Comment: first bloc kdiv deleting propelry .but not other div

Comment: @vision I didn't get you. Can you please help me with an `jsfiddle`, I will definitely help you out.

Comment: i have similar 5 to 10 blocks .your code working only for first block .if i click delete on next block .alert() will come but not empty div

Comment: In that case, try this `$(this).closest('div').next('div').html('');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155264/discussion-between-vision-and-shiladitya).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#deleteAssocPesident').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().siblings('div#deletePresidentBlock:first').html('');
});
```

Comment: You don't need :first if you have unique id. It is when you have class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#deleteAssocPesident').click(function(e){
  // e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);

  //$('#deletePresidentBlock').html('');
  $(this).parent().next('div').children('#deletePresidentBlock').html('');
});
```